# Show unit of weight in product page for Opencart 2

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

Hi!

How to display the unit of weight (kg., gr., oz., ml.,) in product page in Opencart 2.0.2.0

Now only displays a number without units.

I'm Using the default template

in file **template\product\product.tpl** it looks like this:

```
...<li><?php echo $text_model; ?> <?php echo $model; ?></li>

<?php if ($weight) { ?>

<li><?php echo $text_weight; ?>
<?php
echo round($weight, 2)?></li>
 <?php } ?> ...
```

in

**catalog\controller\product\product.php**

I have added the line

```
$data['text_weight'] = $this->language->get('text_weight');

$data['weight'] = $product_info['weight'];
```

what else need to add or perhaps change ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like in default OpenCart code.

## Step 1

Open file `catalog/controller/product/product.php`

**Find** (around line 242):

```
$data['text_tags'] = $this->language->get('text_tags');
```

**Add after :**

```
$data['text_weight'] = $this->language->get('text_weight');
```

## Step 2

In the same file `catalog/controller/product/product.php`

**Find** (around line 270):

```
$data['points'] = $product_info['points'];
```

**Add after :**

```
$data['weight'] = $product_info['weight'];
$tablewunit = $this->db->query("SELECT wcd.unit FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "weight_class_description wcd WHERE (wcd.weight_class_id = " . $product_info['weight_class_id'] . ") AND wcd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "'");
$data['weightunit'] = $tablewunit->row['unit'];
```

## Step 3

Open file `catalog/language/english/product/product.php`

**Find** (around line 6):

```
$_['text_model']               = 'Product Code:';
```

**Add after :**

```
$_['text_weight']       = 'Weight:';
```

## Step 4

Open file `catalog/view/theme/default(your theme)/template/product/product.tpl`

**Find** (around line 141):

```
<li><?php echo $text_model; ?> <?php echo $model; ?></li>
```

**Add after :**

```
<li><?php echo $text_weight; ?> <?php echo $weight . ' ' . $weightunit; ?></li>
```

and then check it.

Comment: Thank you very much! 
It Works ! 
I promise to begin advanced study php and Opencart!

Comment: Also modified for oc3.0.2 and works great! Thank you)